# How to join two LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have two related entities with composite keys:

```
public class Event
{
    public string ID1 { get; set; }
    public int ID2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public string EventData { get; set; } 
    public string DocID1 { get; set; }
    public int DocID2 { get; set; }
}

public class EventDocument
{

    public string ID1 { get; set; }
    public int ID2 { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a possibility to filter first both of them by some criteria and then to join results because of big amount of records?

Acctually I can reach related Events when I filter EventDocuments, but I also need a possibility to filter Event and EventDocument in one time.

I am trying to do like this:

```
var events = ModelContext.Events.AsNoTracking().Select(x => x);
events = events.Where(x => x.EventData.StartsWith(FilterCriteria));


var eventDocuments = ModelContext.EventDocuments.AsNoTracking().Select(x => x);
eventsDocuments = eventDocuments.Where(x => x.LastName.StartsWith(FilterLastName));
```

And now I need to join these to queries and get a result - filtered and joined data from two entities

Trying to do like this:

```
var result = eventDocuments.Join(events, 
                        doc => new { doc.ID1, doc.ID2 }, 
                        ev => new { cross.DocID1, cross.DocID2}, 
                        (doc, ev) => new { EventDocument = doc, Event = ev });
```

Comment: Yes join the events to eventDocuments. What is the problem?

Comment: Got an error and don;t understant it: Severity Code Description 
Error CS0411 The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(IEnumerable<TOuter>, IEnumerable<TInner>, Func<TOuter, TKey>, Func<TInner, TKey>, Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: *Why* are you asking about joining? If you load an eventDocument, EF will also load its Events, provided you use tell it to `Include()` them

Comment: I have a ralation between entities

Comment: @Songaila then why are you asking about joining at all? Define the conditions you want in the `Where` clause. Once you load an eventDocument, its related events will also be loaded

Comment: Because I don't know how to filter both entities by some unknown criterias ... User will enter these criterias, and be able to enter one or two or many criterias.

Comment: And I want to load Events, not Documents ...

Comment: For example: I need Event where EventDate in some interval and also contains EventDocument where Number is equal some value

Comment: @Songalia this has nothing to do with *joining.* `Event` should have an `EventDocument` property though. If it did, you could specify the criteria in the `Where` function, eg `events.Where(evt=>evt.LastName.StartsWith(abc))`.

Comment: Really.. I have allready EventDocuments when filtering Events also.. so what is the way to put tehm to one list?

Comment: Besides the comments about using navigation properties (which I agree is the better way), the problem with your `Join` attempt is the anonymous types used for join keys - as explained in the [How to: Join by Using Composite Keys (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907099.aspx), *The **names** of the properties, and the order in which they occur, must be **identical** in each key*. e.g. `ev => new { ID1 = cross.DocID1, ID2 = cross.DocID2 }` should fix the error.

Comment: ok, going to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply query both sets with `SelectMany`. In query syntax this would look like:

```
var eventsQry =
    from eventDocument in eventDocuments
    where eventDocument.LastName.StartsWith(FilterLastName)
    from ev in events
    where ev.EventData.StartsWith(FilterCriteria) && (ev.ID1 == eventDocument.ID1) && (ev.ID2 == eventDocument.ID2)
    select new { eventDocument, ev };
```

You don't need to use one query to filter your results. You can combine multiple queries:

```
var eventsQry =
    from ev in events
    where ev.EventData.StartsWith(FilterCriteria)
    select ev

var documentsQry =
    from eventDocument in documentsQry
    where eventDocument.LastName.StartsWith(FilterLastName)
    select eventDocument;

var combinedQry =
    from eventDocument in documentsQry
    from ev in eventsQry
    where (ev.ID1 == eventDocument.ID1) && (ev.ID2 == eventDocument.ID2)
    select new { eventDocument, ev };
```

Comment: But I need to filter by many and different criterias every time, and tables have many columns, jus described some... So I thought I can fiter first and then join?

Comment: You can define separate queries and join them then.